# Clear textarea in IE9-10

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, textarea

This does not work in IE10 but it does in other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/54EKK/2/

If you enter text in the textarea and set the variable, the variable retains the contents of the textarea.

Of course if you set the variable before adding content (outside of the function) it will be empty, but in my project I can not do that. Here is a demo of that. It works in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/54EKK/3/

Now my question is if there is a way to empty the textarea while still keeping the variable in the function. BTW emptying the value does not help either.

Thanks for your insights guys!

(I am afraid of not being clear in how I explained things so please tell me if not!).

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Then just set the value of the textarea to an empty string: http://jsfiddle.net/54EKK/7/

Comment: @Guffa oh it works! I tried that and it didn't... must have made another mistake then! Thanks, will try that out. you should edit your answer :).

Comment: Are you just trying to reset the form? If so, did you try to simply call `reset()` on the form element (or use an `<input type="reset">`)?

Comment: because I also want to replace the form by a spinning circle and then add it again :). (yes I could just hide it but whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that only works in IE9. I have tried Firefix, Chrome, Safari and Opera, and neither gets you the `textarea` content when using `innerHTML`.

When you use `innerHTML`, that will give you the `value` *attribute*, which is the original text that was set in the form field. The value that you type into the form field is in the `value` *property*.

If you want the content of the form fields when using `innerHTML`, you have to copy the value property into the value attribute for each form field.

---

#### Edit:

As your clarified that what you really want is to just clear the `textarea`, then set the value of the `textarea` element to an empty string.

You need to access the element, so you might want an id on it:

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

Then when you want to clear it, you get the reference to it and clear the value:

```
document.getElementById('txt').value = '';
```

Comment: you got it reversed. I want to empty the textarea. However what happens is that the textarea Value gets stored with innerHTML. This also happens in IE9 indeed!